# Formating string value

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem with formating input value. Here is a snippet:

```
<input
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  name="time"
  formControlName="time"
  (input)="convertToMinute($event.target.value)"
/>
```

Here is a function:

```
 convertToMinute(value: string) {
    console.log(value);
    let minute = value.slice(0, 2);
    let seconds = value.slice(2, 4);
    let result = minute + ":" + seconds;
    console.log(result);
  }
```

But result is when i enter 500 it's turn to 50:0. I need to replace it with 05:00. What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

We have built in pipes. Please check the documentation https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe. I think 4th option is what you are looking at.

```
{{ dateObj | date }}               // output is 'Jun 15, 2015'
{{ dateObj | date:'medium' }}      // output is 'Jun 15, 2015, 9:43:11 PM'
{{ dateObj | date:'shortTime' }}   // output is '9:43 PM'
{{ dateObj | date:'mm:ss' }}       // output is '43:11'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `padStart()` to complete raw value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

```
let raw_val = '500';

let full_val = raw_val.padStart(4, '0');


let minutes = full_val.slice(0,2);
let seconds = full_val.slice(2);

console.log(`${minutes}:${seconds}`);
```

output

```
 "05:00"
```

JS Bin here: https://jsbin.com/ruyerafepe/edit?js,console

Comment: It's should be looks like when i type 500 directly patch "05:00" on input

Comment: There is a very good module https://jsdaddy.github.io/ngx-mask-page, can be used for input masking.

Comment: Set value using `$event.target.value = converted_value`, and pass `$event` in `convertToMinute($event)` instead of `$event.target.value`, and your `raw_val` would be `$event.target.value`.

Comment: above plugin i tried but not working that hour mask

Comment: Ngx-mask is very straightforward, it should work. Do some debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Input type of your input is text hence i think pipe option may not work.

```
 convertToMinute(value: string) {
       console.log(value);
       let seconds = value.slice(value.length-2, value.length);
       console.log(seconds);
       let minute = '';
       if((value.length-seconds.length)<2) {
         minute = '0'+value.slice(0, 1);
       } else {
         minute = value.slice(0, 2);
       }

       let result = minute + ":" + seconds;
       console.log(result);
  }
```